# randomForest in R: Is there a possibility of calculating casewise confidence intervals?

Tags: r, random-forest, confidence-interval

R package *randomForest* reports mean squared errors for each **tree** in the forest. I need, however, a measure of confidence for each **case** in the data. Since *randomForest* calculates the casewise predictions by averaging the predictions of the single trees, I guess that it should also be possible to calculate a casewise standard error and thus a confidence interval. Can this be done using the output randomForest object (if so: how?) or do I have to dig into the source code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to dig into the source code. You only need to read the documentation. `?predict.randomForest` states that one of its arguments is called `predict.all`:

> **predict.all**  Should the predictions of all trees be kept?

So setting that to `TRUE` will keep a prediction for each case, for each tree, which you can then use to calculate standard error for each case.

I have recently been made aware of [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.4555.pdf) paper by Stefan Wager, Trevor Hastie and Brad Efron which investigates more rigorously the idea of standard errors for the predictions generated by random forests (and other bagged predictors).

Comment: Sorry for asking here. But just to be sure , here RandomForest type is predictions, otherwise we can't speak about confidence interval, isn't?

Comment: @agstudy Not sure I follow. I will readily grant that the _statistical_ meaning of prediction intervals may very well be questionable here, but on some level the predictions are just averages, so calculating a "confidence interval" for each one in a naive way really does just amount to calculating the CI for a mean. Whether the resulting interval means anything useful is obviously a separate question...

Comment: Thanks. My question is because we can randomForest performs classification or regression( object$type ='predictions'). So is calculating CI in the case of classification, has any statistical meaning?

Comment: @agstudy Oh, I see. Yeah, this answer (and really, the question) only makes much sense if they are building a regression tree. If they're doing classification, this whole idea sort of breaks down.

Comment: Thanks. I am asking for evidence because I am not statistician. Otherwise does the answer of @Eric [Here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13869/compare-r-squared-from-two-different-random-forest-models) is a beginning of answer?

Comment: @joran - I think I read the documentation a dozen of times but I did not recognize that this is the option that I was looking for...

Comment: @joran - If it is correct to calculate casewise predictions (in a regression context, of course) as averages of the single tree predictions, than IMHO it should also be meaningful to characterise the variation of the tree predictions around these averages.

Comment: @joran - Browsing through the stackoverflow it became clear to me that in fact I'm looking for *prediction intervals*, something that expresses uncertainty surrounding the predicted y of a single case (while a confidence interval expresses uncertainty about the expected value of y). The predict-method for randomForests does not allow anything in that direction: no options such as `interval="prediction"` or `interval="confidence"` as for linear models. Any cue how prediction intervals could be calculated for randomForests predictions?